# Translation of US Army motto "This We'll Defend"

Tags: english-to-latin-translation, translation-check, motto

I am looking for a good translation of the US army motto, which is:

> This We'll Defend

There are three variants of translation I have found:

1

> Haec protegimus

2

> Is nos mos vallo

3

> Hoc defendam

Are there any, among the three, that are obviously wrong?

Which seems to fit meaning and context best?

Answer (score 4):

Two looks the most wrong, like Google Translate bad.

One appears to have a declension error and conjugation error, and literally means "This (feminine thing). We are defending." (bear in mind that the *this* here is not grammatically connected to the verb here"

The translation relies on what the "this" that the motto refers to. If it is *this* being land, country, i.e. America, than **haec** or rather **hanc** would be correct.

If the *this* is a general thing, than **hoc** would be proper.

I'd render the phrase thusly:

This, we'll defend

**Hanc defendemus** Literally "We will defend this (country, land)" with hanc representing terra, patria, America etc.

Comment: Surely, haec in version 1 is meant to be neuter accusative plural, not feminine nominative singular; therefore, 'Haec protegimus' is perfectly correct, grammatically speaking. And it's not uncommon for Latin to use the plural 'these' where English uses the singular 'this'. It depends what the referent of 'this' is understood to be, I suppose.

Comment: *Defendemus* surely? Also, doesn't the English motto intentionally leave it open exactly what they're defending? Sure, if it's *patria* or *libertas*, they're feminine. But what if it is *deos publicos suosque patrios ac penates*? ;)

Comment: You are correct, defendemus, sorry was a tad distracted there. @cnread Sure, but like I said, we don't know that the "this": is. During the Oath of Enlistment, servicemembers swear to uphold and defend the Constitution of the United States, *constitutio* is feminine, likewise, the Army's general mission is to defend the country, *terra* and *patria* are likewise feminine. So while **haec** "these things" could be valid, I see it as less likely, and someone looked up the Latin word for "this" followed by the Latin for "we defend"